# Getting results of a search - lucene 4.4.0

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine

I'm experiencing some problems on lucene. I'm querying a database. 
As far as i know the indexes are OK (i checked it with lukeall-4.4.0). the Query is constructed as following:

```
                Q = Query.split(" ");

                booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

                //Query[] Queryy = new Query[5 + 5 * Q.length];
                Query[] Queryy = new Query[3 + 3*Q.length];

                //USING THE ALL TEXT
                Queryy[0] = new TermQuery(new Term("DESIGNACAO", Query));
                Queryy[1] = new TermQuery(new Term("DESCRICAO", Query));
                Queryy[2] = new TermQuery(new Term("TAG", Query));

                //USING THE SEPARETED VALUES 
               for (int i = 3, j = 0; j < Q.length; i++, j++) {

                    Queryy[i] = new TermQuery(new Term("DESIGNACAO", Q[j]));
                    Queryy[++i] = new TermQuery(new Term("DESCRICAO", Q[j]));
                    Queryy[++i] = new TermQuery(new Term("TAG", Q[j]));

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < Queryy.length; i++) {
                    booleanQuery.add(Queryy[i], BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
                }
```

The query is OK. For searching for "not or" the query (a booleanQuery) is going to be as following:

```
 +DESIGNACAO:not or  +DESCRICAO:not or  +TAG:not or  +DESIGNACAO:not +DESCRICAO:not +TAG:not +DESIGNACAO:or +DESCRICAO:or +TAG:or
```

I'm using SimpleAnalyser, thus the words not and or will not be removed. The problem is that i can't get hits. I can only have hits if i make a search with lukeall-4.4.0 but not with my code. My search method is the following one:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(directory1);
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(50, true);
        searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        searcher.search(booleanQuery, collector);
        hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
        int total = collector.getTotalHits();
        displayResults();
```

Is there anything wrong in collecting the data or something??

Kind regards

Comment: How are our creating the booleanQuery? Can you show that?

Comment: JtheRocker, i've edited my question ;)

Comment: So, jsut to confirm you are searching for 'not' in field DESIGNACAO, right?

Comment: Yes. I'. Trying to search "not or" in all fields and "not" or "or" in all fields: DESIGNACAO, TAG and DESCRICAO. You see, im trying to find any matches with the all sentence "not or" or the separated words. ;)

Comment: What is Query=? I mean the string you are spliting?

Comment: In this case is the user input: "not or"

Comment: I have answered, can you check if that'll help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piece of cake. The problem was in the construction of the query:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Queryy.length; i++) {
    booleanQuery.add(Queryy[i], BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
```

The `BooleanClause.Occur.MUST` means that this has to exist. Thus, all the terms i was adding to the booleanquery must exist (term1 AND term2 AND term3). The correct is:

```
booleanQuery.add(Queryy[i], BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

This way I can say that has to exist one of those terms I have added (term1 OR term2 OR term3).

Kind regards